# Появление границ у картинки через некоторое время после нажатия на нее

Tags: settimeout

На сайте есть картинка, необходимо, чтобы при клике на нее, либо при наведении появлялась граница, НО через время.

Answer (score 1):

```
.image {
  border: none;
}

.image:hover {
  border: solid 1px black;
  transition-delay:3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout = null;
var img = document.getElementById("test-img");
var defaultColor = img.style.borderColor;

img.onmouseover = function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        img.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }, 1000);
};

img.onmouseout = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    img.style.borderColor = defaultColor;
};
```